# What did the Romans call Cardigan the town in West Wales, UK?

Tags: roman-kingdom

I understand that the Romans made an encyclopedia of all their territory and I would like to know  what they called Cardigan as I am trying to date a milestone built upside down into my cottage.

Comment: Do you have any research showing that the town *existed* in Roman times?

Comment: May be useful: http://www.dyfedarchaeology.org.uk/projects/romanmilitary.htm

Answer (score 3):

Cardigan did not exist in Roman times. It was established by the Normans in the 12th century. The nearest known Roman remains to Cardigan are in Carmarthen, about 25 miles away. The entire area was in the Irish sphere of influence before 700 AD.